# How does a beginner learn to build a Google Tasks client for OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, desktop-application, google-tasks-api

I really wish there was a google tasks app for OS X.  Reminders does not work with Google Tasks.  There is a GTasks API available so it could be done, right?  I have never coded a thing in my life.  I am downloading Xcode right now.  I'd like to have an app for the desktop  and I am willing to learn, could you point me in a good direction? Thanks a lot.

Comment: SO is a QA site and community and your question has to be very specific and technical problem which you cant solve. You better Google to find programming books and articles.

Answer (score 0):

Start to looking for xcode tutorials and code a lot of sample Programms.
Writing a google task app is rly a wrong way to gettin started in programming.

maybe you can use "any.Do" for Google Chrome to sync your google Tasks